# What is the manufacturer of this 1990s toilet?

Tags: toilet

[image]

I'm going to get a better pic today. But this toilet is from 1991, bone in color and elongated. The elongated toilet seat replacements at Home Depot are an inch or two too short.

We just purchased this home and are trying to find the manufacturer. So far, we are unable to locate any identifying marks.

Ok, we just found a number inside the tank, 1957 12 7 89. I'm trying to look it up now.

Thank you, Susan

Comment: This can be absolutely anything. American Standard? You may be better off replacing the whole toilet and buying a few extra seats.

Comment: Look at the top of the bowl, between/behind the bolt-holes for the seat - that's the most common location for a brand-name IME. Sometimes there will be something stamped into the inside of the tank, too.

Comment: Go buy some Kohler toilets and just replace them. The new ones take so little water to flush they'll pay for themselves in time

Comment: Did you look under the tank lid?

Comment: Ok, we just found a number inside the tank, 1957 12 7 89

Comment: 12 7 89 is the date it was made, almost certainly. Might be an Eljer Preserver?

Comment: Yep! It Is Eljer Preserver! I just looked it up!  Thanks to all! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Without gettng anything useful directly from the number, my search on the number lead me to a "[toilet identification page](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/eljer-toilets.html)" where the peculiar shape of the tank provided the tentative ID (Eljer Preserver) in my comment.

[image]